# On dismiss iAd Screen ipad screen becomes black

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, iad

I have a tab based application.I have created a iad object in appdelegate class and using it in my three view controller class.It is working good on tab 2's first screen and tab 3's first screen.On tab 2 there is a table view ,on clicking the row of that table view i navigate to the new view where i have used the same code for iad .on clicking the iad iad screen opens in landscape mode and when closing the screen becomes black and log the following.

**[ADHostWindowController supportsOrientation:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x100bc740**

I have created the object in app delegate like this..

```
self.bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]init];
[self.bannerView setDelegate:self];
```

iam adding banner in view controllers like this
[[[self appdelegate] bannerView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, hightofView-180, 768, 66)]

All my view controllers are in portrait but iads always open in landscape mode.
how to solve this ,this is working in ios 6 ,but this problem is only with ios5 ipad.how to solve thgis .plz help me .any advise will be appreciated.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iad is not the problem as it looksfrom your question  just check what u do when the view disappears on which you are showing iads,